# First JavaScript function/link stops working?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I'm trying to do a simple function where my div can be changed with a click of a link. Everything works fine except for when I click on my first link again, it stops working. The others continue to work.
Here is my code; I hope someone can help me!

```
<script>
function changedivVIDEO(){
var div = document.getElementById("fw14video");
div.innerHTML = "<div id='main2'>Hello</div>";
}

function changedivCAMPAIGN(){
var div = document.getElementById("fw14campaign");
div.innerHTML = "<div id='main3'>Hello</div>";
}

function changedivRUNWAY(){
var div = document.getElementById("fw14campaign");
div.innerHTML = "<div id='main4'>Hello</div>";
}


</script>

<div id="main">

<div id="fw14video"></div>
<div id="fw14campaign"></div>
<div id="fw14runway"></div>
<div id="fw14runway"></div>

</div>


<p><a href="javascript:changedivVIDEO();"><h3>VIDEO</h3></a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:changedivCAMPAIGN();"><h3>CAMPAIGN</h3></a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:changedivRUNWAY();"><h3>RUNWAY</h3></a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:changedivACCESSORIES();"><h3>ACCESSORIES</h3></a></p>

</div>
```

Comment: post your markup here to give us more details

Comment: Is your first link inside #fw14video? If so, you are removing the link the click handler is bound to when you replace the div.

Comment: Which would be and what should be calling the first link?

Comment: also, the 2 IDs are different. Is this intended?

Comment: How/where are you binding the event handlers? I assume you are replacing the elements the handlers were bound to. Either add the event handlers to the new elements or use event delegation.

Comment: just updated! sorry I'm so new to this, I'm not used to all the terminology. if you could please simplify your answers! thanks so much!!!

Comment: Your code seems to "work" just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/n3KxM/. Repeatingly clicking the links updates the other divs. Since the first link is always setting the same content in the same div there are no visible changes when you click it multiple times. So, it looks like you don't have a problem, or at least not the one you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
function changedivRUNWAY(){
var div = document.getElementById("fw14campaign");
div.innerHTML = "<div id='main4'>Hello</div>";
}
```

Should be:

```
function changedivRUNWAY(){
var div = document.getElementById("fw14runway");
div.innerHTML = "<div id='main4'>Hello</div>";
}
```

As a starter...and then if nothing else is missing in the code you posted there's a lose < /div> tag.

Comment: GOT IT!!! THANKS SO MUCH GUYS!!! I just changed the ("WHATEVER") to the div i was supposed to change! Silly me! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I made an [example](http://codepen.io/konsumer/pen/yJCwm) that fills in the details I think are missing:

```
<div id="fw14video"></div>
<div id="fw14campaign"></div>
<a href="" onclick="changediv1();">changediv1</a>
<a href="" onclick="changediv2();">changediv2</a>
<a href="" onclick="changediv3();">changediv3</a>
<script>
function changediv1(e){
  var div = document.getElementById("fw14video");
  div.innerHTML = "<div id='main2'>div1</div>";
  e.preventDefault();
}

function changediv2(e){
  var div = document.getElementById("fw14campaign");
  div.innerHTML = "<div id='main3'>div2</div>";
  e.preventDefault();
}

function changediv3(e){
  var div = document.getElementById("fw14campaign");
  div.innerHTML = "<div id='main4'>div3</div>";
  e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

This works as intended. I am using e.preventDefault() to make it not follow the links, and set text different so you can tell which got clicked. Some questions:

- do you mean for the IDs to be different?
- how did you bind your functions to the links? (I used onclick.)